# Sitecore-Web Api User authentication

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I want to send the sitecore data to authenticated user only..How to pass the HttpWebRequest  object to DownloadString function of webclient....DownloadString cannot take HttpWebRequest  as a parameter.I was following this link 
[Sitecore 7.2 - Item Web API-User Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383502/sitecore-7-2-item-web-api-user-authentication)

```
var client = new WebClient();

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://gyldendal.local/-/item/v1/?sc_itemid={110D8759F-DEA9-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}&sc_database=master");

    request.Headers["X-Scitemwebapi-Username"] = "admin";
    request.Headers["X-Scitemwebapi-Password"] = "b";
 var apiResponse = client.DownloadString(request);
            dynamic jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(apiResponse);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the response from the request object directly.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("...");

    request.Headers["X-Scitemwebapi-Username"] = "sitecore\admin";
    request.Headers["X-Scitemwebapi-Password"] = "b";

    //(...)

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
       var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
       var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

       string apiResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Also, you need to inform the domain in the user name. Like `sitecore\admin`

Cheers

Comment: Hello robert, what is response here?

Comment: HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); but still this gives me {"statusCode":401,"error":{"message":"Access to site is not granted."}}

Comment: Sorry Salman. I edited the answer to include the response object

Answer (score 3):

...and here is a way to do it using the Web API framework; just because i am a fan of async.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("..."),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get
                };

                request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", "sitecore\admin");
                request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Password", "b");

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseString= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I happen to like using [`RestSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) over `HttpWebRequest`, so thought I'd add another version to the list:

```cs
// Build a client pointing to your sitecore instance
IRestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://gyldendal.local/");
// Add credentials to all future requests
restClient.AddDefaultHeader("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", @"sitecore\admin");
restClient.AddDefaultHeader("X-Scitemwebapi-Password", "b");

// Build a request to the item api
IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/-/item/v1/", Method.GET);
// specify API parameters
restRequest.AddParameter("sc_database", "master");
restRequest.AddParameter("sc_itemid", "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}");

#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine( restClient.BuildUri(restRequest) ); // http://gyldendal.local/-/item/v1/?sc_database=master&sc_itemid={110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}
#endif

// Execute request
IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

// Confirm successful response
if (restRequest.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    /* Work with restResponse.Content */
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine(restResponse.Content); // {"statusCode":200,"result":{....}}
#endif
}
```

Also, just so it's clear, confirm the itemwebapi has been enabled on your specific `<site>`. For a default install, you can use the following patch file to enable it:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="website">
        <!-- Options: Off|StandardSecurity|AdvancedSecurity -->
        <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
        <!-- Options: ReadOnly|ReadWrite -->
        <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
        <!-- Options: True|False -->
        <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">False</patch:attribute>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```